# Problems using WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER with Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just implemented the **WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER** code on a new table trigger and now regular users who insert to the table are receiving the following error: *Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "dbo" does not exist, cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.*

Users who are setup as sysadmins have no problem inserting to the table, no errors.  What type of rights need to be granted to users/roles in order for them to be able to use **WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER**?

Comment: Pretty sure they just need permissions on the dbo schema or they have to be assigned to a database role that has access to that schema.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently problem was unrelated to permissions after all but instead related to the fact that "dbo does not exist".  Current db owner was set to an old login which no longer exists.

Fixed this by running the following SQL statement:

```
ALTER DATABASE [DB]
SET SINGLE_USER
GO
EXEC sp_changedbowner 'sa'
GO
ALTER DATABASE [DB]
SET MULTI_USER
```